# issue while committing data using SQLAlchemy Session object in a Loop

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am having a database committing problem with SQLalchemy. Here is my scenario I have a list of records to be added into a table. Once a records is added into a table I need to get the inserted records Id and do another insert into a second table. I am doing these operation under single session. The code structure is given below as I am not allowed to give the code

creates a session object

loop the records list to be inserted:

```
 do the session.add(obj)

 session.commit()

 get obj.id

 do the session.add(obj2) # with obj2 having the id from the obj

 session.commit()
```

here only the last record data is getting committed properly if we have multiple records

Could any one please help me correct this issue.

Comment: impossible to tell, write some sample code, which has the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try restructuring your code to use this:

```
Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(...)
def transaction(self, callback):
  session = sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session(Session)
  try:
    result = callback(session)
  except:
    session.rollback()
    raise
  else:
    session.commit()
  finally:
    session.close()
  return result
```

Then each transaction goes in its own function, like so:

```
def updatetxn(pk, newvalue):
  def txn(session):
    obj = session.query(myclass).filter_by(id=pk).one()
    obj.field = newvalue
    session.add(obj)
  return txn

transaction(updatetxn(4, 'abc'))
```

Handling the commit/rollback logic in one place, and relying on function scope to scope a unit of work, may reduce the complexity of your application and eliminate bugs you haven't found yet.

Answer (score 8):

There's a very good chance that you *don't* need to issue two commits;  One of the main reasons for using sqlalchemy sessions is that it understands how objects can interrelate, and will order its inserts in such a way that data gets properly inserted and correctly represents the desired structure.  This works principally through the `relationship` construct.  Here's a simple example:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import *
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import *
>>> from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
>>> Base = declarative_base()

>>> class A(Base):
...     __tablename__ = "a_table"
...     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
... 
>>> class B(Base):
...     __tablename__ = "b_table"
...     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
...     a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(A.id))
...     a = relationship(A)
... 
>>> my_a = A()
>>> my_b = B()
>>> my_b.a = my_a
>>>
```

The most important part is that we are declaring a relationship between `A` and `B` through `B.a`.  To take best advantage of this, it's important to express the relationship between instances of each through this relationship property, and let sqlalchemy take care of setting the `a_id` column itself.

```
>>> engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
>>> Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
>>> engine.echo = True
>>> Session = sessionmaker(engine)
>>> 
>>> session = Session()
>>> session.add(my_a)
>>> session.add(my_b)
>>> 
>>> session.commit()
```

With `echo=True`, the output looks a bit like this:

```
2011-09-16 17:19:22,367 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...ed50 BEGIN (implicit)
2011-09-16 17:19:22,368 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...ed50 INSERT INTO a_table DEFAULT VALUES
2011-09-16 17:19:22,368 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...ed50 ()
2011-09-16 17:19:22,369 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...ed50 INSERT INTO b_table (a_id) VALUES (?)
2011-09-16 17:19:22,369 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...ed50 (1,)
2011-09-16 17:19:22,369 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...ed50 COMMIT
```

Notice that the `my_a` object is inserted, and sqlalchemy reads the assigned primary key and uses that for the insert for `my_b`.